# Perl how decode pw SHA-1 Base64

Tags: perl, base64, password-encryption

I don't know Perl and I need for some help. I need to encrypt a value and represent it in Base64.. I need to modify these existing code

```
        my $SHAObject = Digest::SHA->new('sha1');
        $Self->{EncodeObject}->EncodeOutput( \$Pw );
        $SHAObject->add($Pw);
        $CryptedPw = $SHAObject->hexdigest();
        $Self->{EncodeObject}->EncodeInput( \$CryptedPw );
```

I have tried to replace hexdigest with encode_base64

```
        my $SHAObject = Digest::SHA->new('sha1');
        $Self->{EncodeObject}->EncodeOutput( \$Pw );
        $SHAObject->add($Pw);
        $CryptedPw = $SHAObject->encode_Base64();
        $Self->{EncodeObject}->EncodeInput( \$CryptedPw );
```

But it do not work..

Someone can help me ? thank you in advance

Giancarlo

Comment: What means "it do not work"?

Comment: Means that when I tried the function the server raise an error.. I do not know Perl so I tried for tentative.. but probably the syntax is wrong

Comment: What error does it give you? We cannot tell you what is wrong without it.

Comment: @GiancarloLori What is the error message?

Answer (score 3):

[`Digest::SHA`](http://search.cpan.org/~mshelor/Digest-SHA-5.95/lib/Digest/SHA.pm) doesn't have an `encode_Base64` method, so it's likely that's what's wrong.

If you refer to the documentation (for OO operations) you can:

```
    $digest = $sha->digest;         # compute digest
    $digest = $sha->hexdigest;
    $digest = $sha->b64digest;
```

I presume it's this last you want, but can't say for sure.

Comment: Thanks. I probably yes. I'll try

Answer (score 0):

You can try https://metacpan.org/pod/Crypt::Digest::SHA1

```
use Crypt::Digest::SHA1 'sha1_b64';

$CryptedPw = sha1_b64($Pw);
```